# ReflectionException Class Mirasvit\Core\Model\ModuleFactory does not exist, when running setup:di:compile or setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, error, exception, setup-di-compile, dicompilation

I received the following error when I run the command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Error

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Mirasvit\Core\Model\ModuleFactory does not exist
```

The extension provider suspect it is trying to access to the older version of the extension, because we can see the new files in the /vendor/ folder that is downloaded via composer.
I also disabled all the caching policies. However, the error still persist.

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions in your root folder? If you are testing in your local environment try to exec "sudo chmod -R 777 .". After that try the setup:upgrade and again exec permissions.

Comment: Hi, yes the permissions are setup correctly. it's testing on the same server as the production server.

Comment: The question is why Mirasvit doesn't support you? They provide a non-working extension, you should ask for refund

Comment: They said is server related issue, and the hosting said otherwise :/ I purchase older versions few months ago, it installed correctly but there are some bug fixes on the newer version, but it won't install correctly through composer :/

Answer (score 0):

The file *vendor/mirasvit/module-core/Model/Module.php* has been removed in the module *mirasvit/module-core* version 1.2.118. To resolve this issue downgrade to version 1.2.114

```
composer req mirasvit/module-core:1.2.114
```

It is imported to pin this version in composer.json as the *mirasvit/module-seo* module defines a lax dependency definition in its' *composer.json*:

```
"mirasvit/module-core": "dev-master|^1.2"
```

So it is definitely a dependency issue Mirasvit should resolve in the next release.